# Importing a shapefile from GitHub using GeoPandas

Tags: shapefile, geopandas, github

I am trying to read a shapefile saved to my github.

```
street_map = gpd.read_file('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nicholasoxford/pythonViz/main/Roads_Atlanta_GA.shp')
```

I get the error:

```
'/vsimem/0ddafba455ae475b9069c0ce6478ea41' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

I thought it might be something with encoding, but I have had no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shapefile consists of at least three mandatory files, the .shp, .shx and .dbf. There can be other optional sidecar files, such as metadata, projection, and indexes (.xml, .prj, .sbn, .sbx).

You have only uploaded the .shp to your git repo, so your shapefile is invalid.

[image]

Once you have uploaded the .dbf and .shx files to your repo, you can read the shapefile (without having to zip the files up) using the special `/vsicurl/` [virtual file system](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html) syntax:

```
import geopandas as gpd
test = gpd.read_file('/vsicurl/https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/raw/master/tests/data/gre.shp')
print(test.head())
```

Comment: I will look into including the other files in a zip.

The thing is, if I have my shp locally or on my google drive it works!
Check out an image here: https://i.imgur.com/YwJkaap.png

Comment: @noxford1 They don't need to be in a zip. See edit. For local files, this is uneccesary as geopandas/fiona knows to look in the same dir for the .shx & .dbf files.